# How to measure width and height, then change parameters before adding view?

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to tell my title to respect that there's a date next to him, so I want to change his width to that of the background, minus the date. But sometimes getMeasuredWidth returns wrong values, or just 0. How do I go about doing this? This method is called for every item.

```
private void populateNewsItems(int pos, List<NewsItem> mFeedItems) {
    NewsItem newsItem = mFeedItems.get(pos);
    View newsContainer = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_news, null);

    TextView background = (TextView) newsContainer.findViewById(R.id.background);
    TextView title = (TextView) newsContainer.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView colorBlock = (TextView) newsContainer.findViewById(R.id.colorBlock);
    TextView date = (TextView) newsContainer.findViewById(R.id.date);
    TextView description = (TextView) newsContainer.findViewById(R.id.description);

    title.setText(newsItem.getTitle());
    date.setText(newsItem.getDate());
    description.setText(newsItem.getDescription());

    title.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    date.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    background.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsTitle = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) title.getLayoutParams();
    paramsTitle.width = background.getMeasuredWidth() - date.getMeasuredWidth();
    title.setLayoutParams(paramsTitle);

    Log.e("LOG", String.format("background width:%d ; date width:%d", background.getMeasuredWidth(), date.getMeasuredWidth()));
    linearLayout.addView(newsContainer);
}
```

It reads the date width absolutely correct. But that's probably because it's the same before that textview gets filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the point that you're asking for the dimensions, your view hasn't been actually drawn yet. If your layout is static, it's best to do it in the XML, but if it's truly dynamic, then you'll want to use an [OnGlobalLayoutListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html) to wait until the view has been first drawn and then resize it. Some code:

```
newsContainer.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // title.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        // date.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        // background.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsTitle = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) title.getLayoutParams();
        // paramsTitle.width = background.getMeasuredWidth() - date.getMeasuredWidth();
        paramsTitle.width = background.getWidth() - date.getWidth();
        title.setLayoutParams(paramsTitle);
        title.requestLayout();
    }
});
```

Comment: Would this work if I'm filling it dynamically? Also, is it efficient to use this? Because it'll be called roughly 20 times at once. I'll try it later, thank you.

Comment: Doing layout statically via XML is more efficient than this approach. It does cause layout to be at least partially repeated. But if you really need dynamic layout, it may be a price that has to be paid.

Comment: Re-looking at your code, I don't see any obvious reason that you shouldn't just be doing this via a weighted horizontal linear layout that wraps the title and date.

Comment: Because I later have to resize another view based on the height of the title TextView. I can solve this a different way, but it's probably the easiest way to solve my other problem.

Comment: @TemporaryName You can use scottt's solution and remove the `GlobalLayoutListener` once you get the height.

Comment: Agreed; if your date and background aren't changing sizes, you can remove the listener once you get the dimensions.

Comment: Also, you should be using the layout widths instead of the measured (pre-layout) widths. I've altered the code sample to reflect this.

Comment: Sadly, my background is changing size. It works perfectly now, but the performance has become very poor, it takes a while to load already, now it takes even longer to display. Anyway, it works, I'll get around to fixing the performance later. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much simpler solution than trying to manually calculate the width. In your xml document containing `R.id.title` and `R.id.background`, try structuring the views a little something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout // this is built to match the width of the background
 android:width="wrap_content"
 android:height="wrap_content"/>
     <TextView
      android:width="wrap_content"
      android:height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/background"/>
     <RelativeLayout
      android:width="match_parent"
      android:height="wrap_content"/>
           <TextView
            android:width="wrap_content"
            android:height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/> // This aligns the date to the 
                                                     // right side of the view
           <TextView
            android:width="match_parent" // this fills the container which matches the width of background, currently
            android:height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/date"/> // and this makes sure the view doesn't overlap the date.
```

The ordering in this actually does matter. You want to list the title after the date so you can reference the date view in the title view. Let me know if you have any more questions and good luck!

Comment: Even though your answer is helpful, it would only half-solve my problem, because I later have to get the height one way or another. But I'll probably implement this, too. Thank you!